# Element not visible error (not able to click an element)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I want to click on a radio button, appears on a webpage. Code is as follow:

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="small-checkbox red-theme raleway-regular text-muted2 position-relative">

        <div class="city-checkbox inline-block position-relative" ng-class="{'rounded-checkbox': main.current_city_id == 1, 'mb-20': main.ifDeviceIsPhone}">
            <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect mh-20" for="mumbaiCity" ng-class="{'is-checked' : main.current_city_id == 1}">
                <input type="radio" id="mumbaiCity" class="mdl-radio__button position-relative vertical-middle" name="city" value="1" ng-click="main.setCity('Mumbai', 1)">
                <span class="mdl-radio__label position-relative font15"><img class="city-icon" src="../../../assets/img/cities/mumbai-icon.png">Mumbai</span>
            </label>
        </div>
</div>
```

**Tesstcase:**

```
// demo-test.js
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000000;

    it('check item count', function() {
        browser.get('<link>');
        element(by.id('mumbaiCity')).click();
    });

});
```

This test throughs error:

> 1) Protractor Demo App check item count
>
> Message:
>
> Failed: element not visible

I also tried with:

```
element(by.css('[ng-click="main.setCity('Mumbai', 1)"]')).click();
```

It gives error:

> [16:16:26] E/launcher - Error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Please suggest, how the radio button will get click?

Comment: why don't you use angularjs to write this js code?

Comment: Its a HTML part of angularjs code

Comment: Have you tried waiting for the element to become visible before executing?  See [Expected Conditions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions)

Comment: see my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871071/click-function-isnt-working-in-protractor-scripts

Comment: Thanks Emma , your question also helped me.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

This is a rather common problem in test automation with selenium.

Here are the common solutions:

- make sure the element you want to click is actually visible. Sometimes you need to make extra actions on a page to make the element visible. For example, open up a dropdown for an option to appear or open menu for submenu to appear
- *[wait](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) for the [visibility](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.visibilityOf) of the element*:

  ```
  var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
  var mumbaiCity = element(by.id('mumbaiCity'));
  browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(mumbaiCity), 5000);
  mumbaiCity.click();
  ```
- there is an *another element* with the same `id` that is actually invisible. In this case, you need to improve your locator to match this specific element. For instance:

  ```
  element(by.css(".city-checkbox #mumbaiCity")).click();
  element(by.css(".city-checkbox input[ng-click*=Mumbai]")).click();
  ```
- Or, if you got multiple elements matching the same locator - you can ["filter"](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) out a *visible element*:

  ```
  var mumbaiCity = element.all(by.id('mumbaiCity')).filter(function (elm) {
      return elm.isDisplayed().then(function (isDisplayed) {
          return isDisplayed;
      });
  }).first();
  mumbaiCity.click();
  ```
- move to element and then click via [`browser.actions()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions):

  ```
  var mumbaiCity = element(by.id('mumbaiCity'));
  browser.actions().mouseMove(mumbaiCity).click().perform();
  ```
- [scroll into view](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) of the element and then click:

  ```
  var mumbaiCity = element(by.id('mumbaiCity'));
  browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", mumbaiCity.getWebElement());
  mumbaiCity.click();
  ```
- click *via javascript* (beware of the [differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562061/webdriver-click-vs-javascript-click) though):

  ```
  var mumbaiCity = element(by.id('mumbaiCity'));
  browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", mumbaiCity.getWebElement());
  ```
- sometimes, you just need to *maximize the browser window*:

  ```
  browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
  ```

Comment: @DoomVroom had a missing `function` statement there, thanks for the heads up.