# protractor if I have many buttons with an ng-click to add them to a collection, how can I test that it adds them correctly?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am making a flower pot application, where you add flowers to it.

So imagine on the page, there are a bunch of flowers, and you can click on some + button to add those flowers to your flower pot.

Each button is basically the following -

```
<button ng-click="model.addToFlowerPot(flower)">Add</button>
```

Right now, I have maybe a dozen flowers from my flowerArray (flower in flowers) and I'm just using a repeater to show them all.

How can I tell protractor to only test one of those buttons to make sure that flower is added to the flowerPot?

I'm not entirely sure after reading http://www.protractortest.org/#/locators

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, first you need to locate the flowers, this is what [`by.repeater()` locator](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.repeater) can help with:

```
var flowers = element(by.repeater("flower in flowers"));
```

Then, you choose what flower you want to work with. Let's say the first one:

```
var flower = flowers.first();  // or flowers.get(0);
```

Then, you can locate the "Add" [button by text](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.buttonText):

```
var addButton = flower.element(by.buttonText("Add"));
addButton.click();
```

---

You can also do that for every flower in the repeater using [`each()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each):

```
flowers.each(function (flower) {
    var addButton = flower.element(by.buttonText("Add"));
    addButton.click();
});
```

Comment: oh... haha well that is certainly a bit more complicated, but also very fundamental to know.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm having some trouble with this.  I get an errror - `Failed: element not visible` :(

Comment: @user1354934 could you check if there is another button element with `Add` text inside each of the repeater elements..please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37815727/771848) - it has an overview of common solutions to this problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: Every button will have "Add" in it.  Thanks for the link - taking a look now.  Sorry about the trouble.