# Element is not clickable at point in protractor

Tags: selenium, protractor, ng-file-upload, gulp-protractor, protractor-net

i have a modal to upload images.when i click on upload image it is navigating to local computer and then pick the specified image.
am getting an error in after navigating to local computer.

error:

> Message:
>       Failed: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (736, 187). Other element would receive the click: ...
>         (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.99)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.14393 x86_64)   Stack:
>       WebDriverError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (736, 187). Other element would receive the click: ...
>         (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.99)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.14393 x86_64)
>           at WebDriverError (C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:27:5)
>           at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:639:15)
>           at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:538:13)
>           at client_.send.then.response (C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:472:11)
>           at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1379:14)
>           at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2913:14)
>           at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2896:21)
>           at asyncRun (C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2820:25)
>           at C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:639:7
>           at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
>       From: Task: WebElement.click()
>           at Driver.schedule (C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:377:17)
>           at WebElement.schedule_ (C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:1744:25)
>           at WebElement.click (C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:1845:17)
>           at actionFn (C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:99:44)
>           at Array.map (native)
>           at C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:406:46
>           at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1379:14)
>           at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2913:14)
>           at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2896:21)
>           at asyncRun (C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2775:27)Error
>           at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:403:27)
>           at ElementArrayFinder._this.(anonymous function) [as click] (C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:101:30)
>           at ElementFinder.(anonymous function) [as click] (C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:740:22)
>           at Object. (C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\example\loginpost.js:40:51)
>           at C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:94:23
>           at new ManagedPromise (C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1082:7)
>           at controlFlowExecute (C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:80:18)
>           at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2913:14)
>           at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2896:21)
>           at asyncRun (C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2820:25)
>       From: Task: Run it("on dashboard") in control flow
>           at Object. (C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:79:14)
>       From asynchronous test:
>       Error
>           at Suite. (C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\example\loginpost.js:16:2)
>           at Object. (C:\Users\Telekha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\example\loginpost.js:1:1)
>           at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>           at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>           at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>           at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>
> 2 specs, 1 failure.

and my code to upload the image:

```
element( by.css('[ng-click="imagePost()"]') ).click();   
browser.sleep(3000);
element(by.model("files")).click();
var path = require('path'); var fileToUpload = 'Desktop:/mdkg.jpg';
var absolutePath = path.resolve(fileToUpload); 
var button = element(by.css('[ngf-select]')); 
button.click(); 
var input = element(by.css('input[type="file"]'));     
input.sendKeys(absolutePath);
element(by.buttonText('Post Image')).click();
```

Comment: First of all format your code. Element you're trying to interact with is behind something else, that's why protractor can't click desired element.

Comment: updated the format. @FCin

Comment: pause your test(`browser.pause()`) before sending file and see if something is blocking your view.

Comment: Starting debugger agent.
Debugger listening on [::]:5858
ControlFlow::2282
| TaskQueue::186
| | (pending) Task::188<then>
| | | TaskQueue::1394
| | | | (pending) Task::1396<Run it("on dashboard") in control flow>
| | | | | TaskQueue::1399
| | | | | | (blocked) Task::1441<<anonymous>>   @FCin

Comment: See the browser, not console. Just look at it and see if some html element is blocking protractor from sending message. The other option is that it tries to send it before the control is loaded. You can try to `browser.sleep(5000)` before sending just to test if this is the case

Comment: Failed: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (736, 187). Other element would receive the click: <div modal-render="true" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal fade ng-isolate-scope in" uib-modal-animation-class="fade" modal-in-class="in" ng-style="{'z-index': 1050 + index*10, display: 'block'}" uib-modal-window="modal-window" index="0" animate="animate" modal-animation="true" style="z-index: 1050; display: block;">...</div>
      (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.99)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 ,platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64).this error getting @FCin

Comment: There are several workaround to make this work.have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809915/element-not-visible-error-not-able-to-click-an-element

Comment: Thanks for the info @SudharsanSelvaraj , and i worked with all the scenarios ,but still getting that.

Comment: if you use `browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", button.getWebElement())` , then definitely it won't throw the same error.

Comment: Could you please also share the Page DOM?

Comment: <img src="images/postimg-icon.png" ng-click="imagePost()" class="m-r" role="button" tabindex="0"> when i click on image icon it's opening a modal and modal contains two buttons like upload and post.when i click on upload it's navigating local system there we can pick the image and we can post.protractor navigating to local system and it is unable to pick the image.@VishalAggarwal

Answer (score 0):

You can use wait element to be clickable

```
 var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
 var element = element(by.xpath([xpath_locator]));
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(by.xpath([xpath_locator]))), 30000).then(function () {
                element.click();
});
```

You can select element by any locator in this case I'm selecting it by xpath, and

Answer (score 0):

Include this statement:

`browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();` into

`onPrepare()` method of `protractor.conf.js` file like given below.

```
onPrepare () {
 browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```