# toThrow to catch protractor error using pageobjects

Tags: selenium, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests

I've started to work with protractor + Jasmine for E2E testing.

The idea is to do an invalid operation and catch the exception:

```
expect(function () { return documentsPanel.clickUploadButtonError(); }).toThrow();
```

The documentsPanel is just a page object with multiple page actions. This is how I'm defining the method:

```
this.clickUploadButtonError = function () {
    return uploadButton.click().thenCatch(function (err) {
        throw('Cannot click upload button.');
    });
};
```

The idea is for expect to pass by catching the error but my test still fails as uploadButton.click() throws a Selenium error:

> Failed: unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point (263, 131).

Any ideas on how can Jasmine catch the Selenium error?

Answer (score 1):

You can provide an *error callback* explicitly:

```
return uploadButton.click().then(function success() {
    console.log("Click was successful");
}, function failure(error) {
    console.log("Click was unsuccessful");
    console.log(error);
});
```

As a side note, if you are interested in tackling the "Element is not clickable" errors, please see [this summary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37815727/771848) of the things to try.

Comment: And how can I catch that error callback with Jasmine? That's my real problem.