# No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id="more"])

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing, google-chrome-headless

**protractor.e2e-sepc.ts**

```
import {browser, element, by} from 'protractor';

describe('Open the link', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
        browser.get('url');
        browser.sleep(2000);

    });

    it('Click on more button', () => {
        element(by.id('more').click();
        })
    })
```

When I ran the above test case on chrome as a browser it ran succcessfully, but when I ran it with chrome **--headless** browser it fails the spec by displaying error as `No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id="more"])`

**protractor.config.js**

```
multiCapabilities: [{
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions': {
            args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu"]
        }
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

My assumption is that the 2-second sleep is not enough and you just need to [explicitly wait](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) for the presence of the desired element:

```
var more = element(by.id('more'));
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(more), 10000)   
more.click();
```

Note that you had a missing closing parenthesis, but I think that's just a typo:

```
element(by.id('more')).click();
//               HERE^
```

Comment: Hi @alecxe I have also tried the method that you worte in your answer following in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809915/element-not-visible-error-not-able-to-click-an-element/37815727   this post.My test ran successfully without headless browser and fails in headless browser.The main thing is that only this id fails otherwise every other tcs run succesfully in headless as well as without headless.I have also changed the id.

Comment: could you make a video or screenshot in headless mode? Maybe there is no such element and protractor is right :)

Comment: also could you change locator and resolve your issue in such way?