# Should I explicitly wait for element to be visible in Protractor test?

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor, end-to-end

If my page is rendered using AJAX request should I execute something like

```
waitForElementToBeVisible('.todoListItem');
//that is my custom function that waits 
//till element will be rendered
```

before making call:

```
element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys('write first protractor test');
```

which sendKeys to element with CSS class `.todoListItem`?

Answer (score 3):

If this is an AngularJS application under test, things should be handled naturally by `protractor` - *it always works in sync with Angular*. This is, though, theory.

In practice, this is not always the case - for instance, our test codebase has the `browser.wait()` calls here and there to make the tests flow the way we want them to work.

Note that [disabling Angular animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584451/how-to-disable-animations-in-protractor-for-angular-js-appliction) and *increasing the implicit wait timeout* sometimes help too.

See also:

- [a custom `waitReady()` function](https://gist.github.com/elgalu/2939aad2b2e31418c1bb) to wait for element to be present and visible
- [`protractor-flake` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-flake) (rerun potentially flakey protractor tests before failing)