# How to disable animations in protractor?

Tags: angular, protractor

I've found some answers on google, but they don't seem to be applicable to my project.

Some of the answers talked about adding some code to their `conf.js` file's `onPrepare()` function, but I don't have that file in my project. I have a file named `protractor.config.js`, which was in the angular quickstart project by default. Anyway, this config file also has an `onPrepare()` function, so I tried to add the code from answer #2 in this question: [How to disable animations in protractor for angular js application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584451/how-to-disable-animations-in-protractor-for-angular-js-application), but then my tests failed with:

```
message: Failed: Trying to load mock modules on an Angular2 app is not yet supported.
```

Comment: The answer you are referencing relates to legacy AngularJS and not the Angular (>= 2.x) platform you are using. Basically though you should just need to swap out `BrowserAnimationsModule` with [NoopAnimationsModule](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/animations/index/NoopAnimationsModule-class.html) according to environment. At least in 4.x.

Comment: @NeilLunn Where to do that? I can't find any `BrowserAnimationModule` in my `protractor.config.js` file.

Comment: @NeilLunn Have you seen my message? :)

Answer (score 8):

If you want to disable the Angular 2 animation go for the answer as commented by @NeilLunn. If you want to disable CSS-animations you can override it with a customer css Javascript injection. The script below can be taken as an example. 
<strike>Place it in the `onPrepare` in your protractor config file</strike>

```js
return browser.driver.executeScript(disableCSSAnimation);

function disableCSSAnimation() {
  var css = '* {' +
    '-webkit-transition-duration: 0s !important;' +
    'transition-duration: 0s !important;' +
    '-webkit-animation-duration: 0s !important;' +
    'animation-duration: 0s !important;' +
    '}',
    head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style');

  style.type = 'text/css';
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
  head.appendChild(style);
}
```

What it will do is it will add a piece of custom CSS to override some animations. This will for example prevent a color animation when you hover.

Hope it helps

**Update:**

The script needs to be injected after loading the url. If you place it in the `onPrepare` and you don't load the url before injecting the script the script will be injected on the `data`-url. Using it like this would do the trick

```js
describe('Demo test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    browser.get('http://www.protractortest.org/#/');
    browser.driver.executeScript(disableCSSAnimation);

    function disableCSSAnimation() {
      var css = '* {' +
        '-webkit-transition-duration: 0s !important;' +
        'transition-duration: 0s !important;' +
        '-webkit-animation-duration: 0s !important;' +
        'animation-duration: 0s !important;' +
        '}',
        head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        style = document.createElement('style');

      style.type = 'text/css';
      style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
      head.appendChild(style);
    }
  });

  it('Should go to Protractor test page', () => {
    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Protractor - end-to-end testing for AngularJS')
  });
});
```

[image]

**Important:**

Make a method of it so you can re-use it because each time the page reloads / goes to an other url, the script needs to be injected.

This should do the trick in the end. Good luck with it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It didn't work unfortunately. This is where I put it: https://gyazo.com/6462058198e0e8c96eb65a370baad172

Comment: Ok, code looks good. What if you add a `browser.sleep(60000)` and then check the DOM, is the code injected?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not able to test it know, will do it tomorrow, let you know

Comment: Thanks a lot! Regarding the Angular 2 animations, you told me to go for Neil Lunn's answer. Could you please elaborate on that, because I don't understand what he wants me to do, and he hasn't replied to me.

Comment: Have you seen my message? :)

Comment: @Jesper, sorry, I don't have experience with Angular 2+ animations. We don't use it in the project I work with. Is there a possibility to create a "special" build without the animations from your CI-pipeline?

Comment: Alright, no problem. Thanks anyway. I will see if I can find a solution.

Comment: In my case it worked better to add : `transition: none !important;` (and all browsers variations).

Answer (score 7):

I managed to accomplish this using a query parameter.

Building on Neils answer I was able to update my SharedModule to switch between `BrowserAnimationModule` and `NoopAnimationModule`.

I created a method that appends a query parameter that I will look for later. I use this method for all navigation in my tests so I can be sure the parameter is always present.

**E2eCommon**

```
public static navigateTo(path: string) {
  browser.get('/' + path + '?qa=true');
  browser.waitForAngular();
}
```

Then in my module where I declare the animation module I check for the query parameter and based on whether or not it's present I either load `BrowserAnimationModule` or `NoopAnimationModule`

**shared.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  exports: [
    AnimationModule(),
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    AnimationModule(),
    ...
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }

export function AnimationModule(): any {
  return window.location.search.indexOf('qa=true') > -1 ? NoopAnimationsModule : BrowserAnimationsModule;
}
```

Comment: very nice solution. I also abstracted the query param ike this `navigateTo(path: string) {
    return browser.get(path + "?qa=true");
  }`